# Demo programs for BBC Micro

Tags: demo, bbc-micro

I have a dim and distant memory of a set of demo programs for the BBC Micro series of home computers which showed off its graphics with images of lissajous figures, planets (spheres rendered with varying densities of dots), and so on.
I've searched the internet for this code but have drawn a blank.
Does anyone else know where I can find them (or screenshots of them)?

Comment: lots of demos for 8bit comps are on youtube.

Comment: Thanks @user1095108 -- I looked, but these were not generally animated demos or videos but static images, IIRC, so I've drawn a blank.

Comment: Come on, donkey, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JoWIxHPGM4 is not static, seek forward a little

Comment: I think perhaps I didn't make my question clear: it is the specific set of demos that I'm remembering that I'd like a copy of (or link to). I know there are other (perhaps better) demos out there, many of which are animated like the one you link to, but it's the "official"(?) original demo code that I'd like to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like various demos that came with the Acorn User magazine throughout its history, however I can't point you to an exact issue. Also, you could try back issues of Beebub magazine or Micro User.

Answer (score 0):

These sound very much like the Creative Graphics programs from Acornsoft, released pretty much as soon as the BBC Micro itself was (early 1982). You could also buy the accompanying book: that pops up on eBay fairly often. You'll find a cassette image of the programs [via Stairway to Hell](https://www.stairwaytohell.com/bbc/archive/tapeimages/leisure/Acornsoft/CreativeGraphics_B.zip), for use with any BBC Micro emulator - I tend to use BeebEm.